# Keep getting ptrace: Operation not permitted when trying to attach to process in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, gdb

I'm running a Flask app in a `python:3.8-alpine` docker container. I'm trying to setup remote debugging in VS Code with debugpy, with the end of my dockerfile being:

```
CMD [ "gunicorn", "app:create_app()", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
RUN python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 --log-to-stderr --pid 1
```

In my docker compose, I have:

```
  api:
    container_name: gamersplane-api
    build:
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    command: gunicorn app:create_app() --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --timeout 600
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 5678:5678
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

But every time I build, I get this error:

```
I+00000.010: Initial environment:
            
            System paths:
                sys.prefix: /usr/local
                sys.base_prefix: /usr/local
                sys.real_prefix: <missing>
                site.getsitepackages(): /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
                site.getusersitepackages(): /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
                sys.path (site-packages): /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
                sysconfig.get_path('stdlib'): /usr/local/lib/python3.8
                sysconfig.get_path('platstdlib'): /usr/local/lib/python3.8
                sysconfig.get_path('purelib'): /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
                sysconfig.get_path('platlib'): /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
                sysconfig.get_path('include'): /usr/local/include/python3.8
                sysconfig.get_path('scripts'): /usr/local/bin
                sysconfig.get_path('data'): /usr/local
                os.__file__: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py
                threading.__file__: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py

I+00000.010: sys.argv before parsing: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debugpy/__main__.py', '--listen', '0.0.0.0:5678', '--log-to-stderr', '--pid', '1']
                    after parsing:  ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debugpy/__main__.py']

I+00000.010: Attaching to process with PID=1

I+00000.010: Code to be injected: 
            import codecs;
            import json;
            import sys;
            decode = lambda s: codecs.utf_8_decode(bytearray(s))[0] if s is not None else None;
            script_dir = decode([47, 117, 115, 114, 47, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 47, 108, 105, 98, 47, 112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110, 51, 46, 56, 47, 115, 105, 116, 101, 45, 112, 97, 99, 107, 97, 103, 101, 115, 47, 100, 101, 98, 117, 103, 112, 121, 47, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114]);
            setup = json.loads(decode([123, 34, 109, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 34, 44, 32, 34, 97, 100, 100, 114, 101, 115, 115, 34, 58, 32, 91, 34, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 34, 44, 32, 53, 54, 55, 56, 93, 44, 32, 34, 119, 97, 105, 116, 95, 102, 111, 114, 95, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 32, 34, 108, 111, 103, 95, 116, 111, 34, 58, 32, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 32, 34, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 95, 97, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 95, 116, 111, 107, 101, 110, 34, 58, 32, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125]));
            sys.path.insert(0, script_dir);
            import attach_pid_injected;
            del sys.path[0];
            attach_pid_injected.attach(setup);
            

I+00000.011: Injecting code into process with PID=1 ...

Attaching with arch: i386:x86-64
Running: gdb --nw --nh --nx --pid 1 --batch --eval-command='set scheduler-locking off' --eval-command='set architecture i386:x86-64' --eval-command='call (void*)dlopen("/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_amd64.so", 2)' --eval-command='call (int)DoAttach(0, "import codecs;import json;import sys;decode = lambda s: codecs.utf_8_decode(bytearray(s))[0] if s is not None else None;script_dir = decode([47, 117, 115, 114, 47, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 47, 108, 105, 98, 47, 112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110, 51, 46, 56, 47, 115, 105, 116, 101, 45, 112, 97, 99, 107, 97, 103, 101, 115, 47, 100, 101, 98, 117, 103, 112, 121, 47, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114]);setup = json.loads(decode([123, 34, 109, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 34, 44, 32, 34, 97, 100, 100, 114, 101, 115, 115, 34, 58, 32, 91, 34, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 34, 44, 32, 53, 54, 55, 56, 93, 44, 32, 34, 119, 97, 105, 116, 95, 102, 111, 114, 95, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 32, 34, 108, 111, 103, 95, 116, 111, 34, 58, 32, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 32, 34, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 95, 97, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 95, 116, 111, 107, 101, 110, 34, 58, 32, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125]));sys.path.insert(0, script_dir);import attach_pid_injected;del sys.path[0];attach_pid_injected.attach(setup);", 0)'
Running gdb in target process.
stdout: b'The target architecture is set to "i386:x86-64".\n'
stderr: b'ptrace: Operation not permitted.\nTarget \'None\' cannot support this command.\nNo symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.\nNo symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.\n'
I+00000.103: Code injection into PID=1 completed.
```

And I'm unable to attach from VS Code. If I use the module method (eg, importing and setting up debugpy), it works. Other sites/SO questions suggest that `cap_add` and `security_opt` are what I needed, but they don't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Possibly [relevant debugpy issue](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/80) and [linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process/41656#41656)?

Comment: `RUN` happens during the image build; the process you start this way doesn't see run-time options like `cap_add:` and isn't persisted in the image.  You'll need to start this debugger a different way.